# How to fix a DB error in a Rails PostgreSQL app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I would like to know how to fix the following error, in a Rails 6 app, that is connected to an RDS database at AWS:

> could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds
>   (waited 5.075 seconds); all pooled connections were in use

**So far I tried:**

- Increasing pool to 100 in database.yml
- Upgrading db instance from 2
  vcpus to 4 cpus. The RAM is 16 GB

Thanks.

Comment: What is current database pool size? What is your maximum number of users that can interact with your webapp simultaneously? Are you using unicorn?

Comment: Your problem is not with DB config, it's with threads not releasing the connection. Like Rustem asked above, how many requests are hitting your application simultaneously? 

You can use `pgbouncer` for the time being though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going through this link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/forked-pg-connections. At least, validate limit for number of active connections that your Postgres server can handle.

If you use Unicorn pre-fork server model, then may be configure before/after hooks to gracefully open and close database connections.

```
before_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    )

end
```